# Problem with reading the image with OpenCV lib

Tags: python, opencv

I started to learn opencv with Python, and right away i get an error. Im trying for an hour to find answer but I failing.

I want to read the image thats saved on my desktop, and py .py file is also saved on deskop.

This is my code:

```
import cv2

my_image = cv2.imread('slika.png', 0)
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'
```

I have installed open cv lib like this:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

When I do:

```
print(dir(cv2))
```

I get this:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'cv2']
```

And this:

```
print(cv2.__file__)

#C:\Users\nenad\OneDrive\Desktop\cv2.py
```

Im using windows, Python 3.7 32-bit and IDLE that came with python (basic one)
I know that this is basic, but what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Depending on how you are set up, you may need to use `pip3 install opencv-python`  if your interpreter is Python3. Using plain  `pip install XYZ` may be installing for Python2. You should state which IDE/editor you are using, if any. Also, is that your complete code, or have you removed other stuff?

Comment: Im using IDLE that came with python (basic one), I installed all my libs with pip, not pip3 and they work fine. 
When Im using ` Python -m pip3 install opencv-python` i get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Ok, please `import cv2` and then `print(dir(cv2))` and paste the output into your question - not the comment area, please.

Comment: Check out the question, I have updated it (I have done what you told me)

Comment: Ok, and the output of `print(cv2.__file__)` ?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: You're importing a local file that is on your desktop called `cv2.py`. Get rid of that. Otherwise, your code is importing THAT instead of OpenCV (because Python will look in local directories first, THEN it will search your python path for libs).

Comment: You need to rename your Python script as say `opencvtest.py` else you are conflicting with the OpenCV package itself.

Comment: @alkasm please post that as answer so that I can confirm the answer  :)

Comment: Probably unlikely to help others as a question since it's more akin to a typo, so I'd recommend deleting it, or finding a good duplicate that isn't specific to opencv and marking as a dupe.